# How do I instiate a class with it's dependencies using Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

In my MVC application I have a concept of "scheduled job".

A job inherits from an interface and is then (via reflection) automatically registered on application start.

Now, in my application I am using Ninject for DI to help make my controllers more unit testable. I would love to use ninject for my Scheduled Jobs too but am currently using "poor man's DI" to instantiate my Job's with their dependencies.

So, how exactly would I use Ninject instead of Poor Man's DI?

Job Interface:

```
public interface IScheduledJob
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use Cron method to return frequency expression
    /// </summary>
    string Frequency { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The entry point of the Job
    /// </summary>
    void DoWork();
}
```

Job Init Code:

```
private void ConfigureSchedules(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Get all types that implement the scheduler interface
        IEnumerable<Type> jobs = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => typeof(IScheduledJob).IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);
        foreach (var jobType in jobs)
        {
            // Create instance of job
            IScheduledJob job = (IScheduledJob)Activator.CreateInstance(jobType);
            // Add to schedule
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => job.DoWork(), job.Frequency);
        }
    }
```

Scheduled Job Ctors:

```
public class SynchronizerScheduledJob : IScheduledJob
{
    #region Private Members

    private IMagentoSoapService _magentoSoapService;
    private IMagentoSoapCredentialProvider _credsProvider;
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private IOrderHubService _orderHubService;

    #endregion

    #region Ctors

    public SynchronizerScheduledJob(
       IMagentoSoapService service,
       IMagentoSoapCredentialProvider credsProvider,
       IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
       IOrderHubService orderHubService)
    {
        _magentoSoapService = service;
        _credsProvider = credsProvider;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _orderHubService = orderHubService;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Poor man's DI Ctor
    /// </summary>
    public SynchronizerScheduledJob() : this(
            new MagentoSoapService(),
            new MagentoSoapCredentialProvider(),
            new UnitOfWork(AppDbContext.Create()),
            new OrderHubService())
    { }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get stuck? If you do not know how, you might want to read how to in [www.ninject.org](http://www.ninject.org/).

Comment: @Win I am stuck when actually trying to instantiate the instance of a class found via reflection with it's dependencies. Controllers are done automatically and that is great but how do I: a) Find out what dependencies a class may have and then b) get those dependencies registered with ninject to init the class.

I have looked all over the website and on github but am struggling to find an example of my usecase. Poor man's DI makes it easy but I am wondering what the Ninject equivalent is.

Comment: a and b are the responsibilities of IoC container (Ninject). All you have to do is to register those dependencies, IoC container will resolve it for your.

Comment: OK. So, register the dependencies as well as any assemblies that implement my IScheduledJob interface? Once I have done that, do I treat ninject almost like a service locator when I setup my job runner? ie get all implementations of my interface from ninject and add them as recurring jobs.